# PHP - Really fast way of detecting white space around an image?

Tags: php, gd

I need a **really** fast method of detecting white space around an image, specifically I need the coordinates of where the first non-white pixel begins for each side (e.g. left, top, right, bottom.)

ImageMagick is too slow, so is looping through each pixel along each side with GD and seeing if it's white. I've got to do about 500,000,000 images so every microsecond makes a difference.

BTW, the image is black & white only.

If there is an external app that can do this, which I can `exec` with PHP, then that would be fine.

Comment: Is the white "border" a nice uniform border around the picture? Is the white really white or only very bright?

Comment: No, it's not uniform at all... could be anything, and different on each side. The image could even be all white.

Comment: So i assume you need the one that "stands out" the most on each side? PS: YOu will most likely get a faster processing speed doing the actual processing in C or C++.

Comment: 500m images - phew! Should love to know your use case!

Comment: This sounds like a job for parallelisation. If you were to farm it out to a bunch of servers - or even a network of desktop PCs - you'd get it done much faster. That said, have you tried `imagemagick` from an SSD or RAM drive?

Comment: Can you give us a more detailed description as to how the pictures look like? I have an algorithm in mind but im not sure if it would be applicable. What im interested in are the common shapes in your pictures. Mostly rectangular shapes rotated/slightly deformed? Mostly circular? Completely unpredictable (like X, E, T...)?

Comment: @halfer: It is farmed out to a bunch of servers, and yes, each is using a RAM drive for temporary storage.

Comment: @KillerX: text, drawing, photos, etc.

Comment: How many servers does one get in a _bunch_? `;)`

Comment: I don't see how PHP is a suitable workhorse for this. If you have that many images, you should use a native language and exploit every performance trick imaginable for each specific file format.

Comment: @Gleno, it's not really suitable, but it's what I'm using. C++ would be much better, Assemby better than that, and a dedicated OS kernel for doing only what I want would be even better, but PHP is what I am working with for practical purposes. Anyway, PHP only pulls together what is mostly done by various other apps written in C or C++ - it just so happens that PHP is being using for this part.

Answer (score 3):

is there any extra information you know about the images that can be used to help?

Like do the images start white then go black then stay black?  or can any pixel be white or black and the fact that any one is white or black doesn't tell you anything about the others?

If any pixel can be white or black regardless of the other pixels then I don't see how you can do much better than checking each pixel in a loop until you find the first non white one...

If you know that if the fifth pixel from the left is white then 0-4 are definitely white as well then you might be able to check fewer pixels instead by using some sort of modified binary type search (as you could skip checking 0-4 in this case and just check say 5, then 10 and if 5 is white and 10 is black you know the point is somewhere between 5-10, so then you can split the difference and check 7 etc etc until you find the point at which they change.)

I think you might end up with a trade off between speed and accuracy here.  The most accurate way is to slice through each column and row, starting at the extremities, checking each pixel.  Once you find a hit in a column you have found the edge on one side.  This could be done in parallel as each check is independent.  you might be able to speed this up by, as you said, checking only every nth pixel, but this is likely to come a cropper occasionally, especially with such a large data set.  this may or may not be acceptable.  you may be able to improve this by checking around the area you find a match to check that the match is accurate.  So if you check every 3rd pixel and you find a hit at pixel 15 then check 14 to see it if is a hit (and 13 if 14 is).  using this you might be able to get away with fewer checks.

Comment: Black pixels tend to be in blocks naturally, so I could get away with skipping every other pixel, or even checking only 1 out of 3. Other than that, it could be text, drawing, or dithered photo on the image.

Answer (score 1):

One algorithm that could work if you have a mostly continuos border of darker pixels:
Left side:

1. Take the middle pixel and start checking the pixels to the right until you find a black one.
2. Then move from there up/down until you hit a black pixel
3. When you find a black pixel move to the left until you hit a white one
4. Repeat 2,3 until you end up at top/bottom

That of course will not work if there are gaps, like in text.

Comment: Thing is... there could be a big white space in the middle of the image, with only black pixels around the corners.

Comment: Theoretically you could start at lets say 10% from the top and go right to 50% of the width. If you dont hit anything move one row up and next move 2 rows down etc... You would most likely still need to cover less pixels than scanning row by row/column by column.